# React with firebase cloud firestore- presenting data from the database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to figure out how to get data out of my cloud firestore.

I have given up trying to figure out how to do it with [react-firestore-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore) and am just trying to get to the same place as I was able to get to before starting with hooks.

In my old componentDidMount I was able to use this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        // const fsDB = firebase.firestore(); // Don't worry about this line if it comes from your config.
        let options = [];
        await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            options.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            options
        });
```

Now, the best I am able to do is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data
    const unsubscribe = fsDB
      .collection("abs_for_codes")
      .onSnapshot(({ docs }) => {
        setFieldOfResearchesOptions(
          // map data to react-select
          docs.map(doc => {
            const { title } = doc.data();

            return {
              value: doc.id,
              label: title
            };
          })
        );
      }, setFieldOfResearchesError);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [setFieldOfResearchesError, setFieldOfResearchesOptions]);
```

This generates content that I can use to populate a select menu. The select options list the title field of the data base in the select menu.

What I am trying to get to is what I was able to do to present the select options in the original version.

That is:

1. Insert a string at the beginning of every value as 'ABS -'
2. Insert the document id of each document after that string
3. Then insert the title.

I had this working in the old componentDidMount.

I can't find a way to get that integrated in the current attempt.

Can anyone see how to change the presentation format of the values that get extracted from cloud firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not wrong, you're calling `unsubscribe` when component unmounts so this way will not work. See => https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Try it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let options = [];
    await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        options.push({
            value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
            label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
          }); 
        });
      setFieldOfResearchesOptions(options);
    });

  }, [setFieldOfResearchesError, setFieldOfResearchesOptions]);
```

Comment: Where does your solution stitch together the 3 steps I set out?

Comment: I understood you did it in your first approach so I skipped that part, but can do it for you if needed

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Thanks for the insights - but I don't get what you're suggesting

Comment: Take a look in your code, you are calling `unsuscribe()`when the component is `unmounting`. Edited for clarification.

Comment: Ups!! omg... i didn't realize xD `unsubscribe` is not a function...

Comment: Sorry - I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Just duplicate your working code in componentDidMount inside `useEffect(() => { ....here... }, [....deps]) and it should work.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know what [...deps] means

Comment: Sorry. I edited again for clarification... i would refer to function dependencies [setFieldOfResearchesError, setFieldOfResearchesOptions]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202920/discussion-between-adolfo-onrubia-and-mel).

Comment: Thanks a lot Adolfo!

Comment: You are wellcome, glad to help